# Bare bones PHP proxy

Tags: php, web-services, curl

I'm not a PHP guy, but I need to set up a bare bones proxy for a web service.  As an example, let's use google.  Let's say that I have a proxy server set up at: http://mydumbproxy.com/index.php and I want it to act just like http://www.google.com/search.  So for instance, if someone typed in the url http://mydumbproxy.com/index.php?q=dancing+banana, they would get the same thing as if they had typed in http://www.google.com/search?q=dancing+banana

How would I do this?

Note: Eventually this will become more than a straight passthrough.  It will provide a security layer between the public at large and dangerous access of the base web service.

Comment: Let's say you included a question.

Comment: Maybe a stupid question, but: Are you going to steal other sites content?! O_o

Comment: Does it have to be done in PHP?  You could set up a legitimate proxy (e.g. apache with mod_proxy might be able to do this)

Comment: @KingCrunch Not stupid question and no.  I'm really trying to hook into a websolr server.  The proxy will eventually provide a security layer so that a user can't just drop our entire index.  Google might be a bad example because the return will either be json, xml, etc.

Comment: @Frank - Yep, PHP.  The people that I hand this over to will need to maintain it.  They speak PHP.  And (as in my last comment) it won't remain "dumb" forever.

Comment: Surely if they have to speak PHP they'll have to know how to admin the Apache installation too.

Comment: you might be able to get away with a simple `URL Rewrite` rather than using PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After starting with Franks answer and googling a bit and put this scrap together which seems to do what I want:

```
<?php
echo file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/search?' . $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], 'r');
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is probably a move in the right direction:

```
fpassthru(fopen('http://www.google.com/search?' . $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], 'r'));
```